# SwiftUI toolbar attaches to every keyboard

Tags: swiftui

I'm following [this page](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-the-keyboard) for how to implement a keyboard accessory in SwiftUI. The done button is showing up and functioning as expected for the TextField I am modifying. However, every other keyboard in the same view also ends up decorated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                        Button("Click me!") {
                            print("Clicked")
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the 2nd TextField here also receiving the Toolbar when it is not being modified? Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `.toolbar` injects toolbar into independently of where do you attach modifier.

Comment: This is my experience too. You have to resort to UIKit to get an exclusive keyboard toolbar

Comment: Thank you both. Weird behaviour, IMO! I'll look into UIKit. Thanks again.

Comment: What, I think, helps put this toolbar feature into perspective is it adds to the touch bar on macOS. With that in mind, it doesn't seem intended to replace the input accessory from UIKit at all. It just does something that looks similar on the surface.